# Which convex functions are characterized as the supremum of linear functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

A convex function $f$ can be represented as the supremum of all the affine functions that are dominated by $f$. Is there a simple characterization of those convex functions $g$ that can be represented as the supremum of all the *linear* functions that are dominated by $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, the function $g$ has this property if and only if there exist $a,b$ with $a\ge b$ and $g=g_{a,b}$, where $$g_{a,b}(t)=\begin{cases}at&(t\ge0),
\\bt&(t<0).\end{cases}$$

It's clear that every such $g_{a,b}$ is the sup of a family of linear functions. Conversely, say $g$ is convex and $g$ is the sup of a family $F$ of linear functions. Let $L_a(t)=at$. There exists $S\subset\Bbb R$ such that $$F=\{L_a:a\in S\}.$$Hence $$g(t)=\sup_{f\in F}f(t)=g_{\alpha,\beta}(t),$$where $\alpha=\sup S$ and $\beta=\inf S$.

(Note we never used the assumption that $g$ is convex. This makes sense: It's clear that the sup of any family of linear functions *is* convex...)

**Edit:** In fact $g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is the supremum of  a family of linear functions if and only if $g$ is convex and $$g(tx)=tg(x)\quad(t\ge 0).$$

Again it's clear that the sup of a family of linear functions has this form. Suppose conversely that $g$ is convex and has that homogeneity property. We know that $g$ is the sup of a family of affine functions. So the following shows that $g$ is the sup of a family of linear functions:

> > Suppose $A$ is affine; write $A=\alpha+L$, where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $L$ is linear. Then $A\le g$ if and only if $\alpha\le0$ and $L\le g$.

Proof: Suppose first that $\alpha\le 0$ and $L\le g$. Since $A\le L$ it is clear that $A\le g$.

Conversely, suppose $A\le g$. Then $\alpha=A(0)\le g(0)=0$, and for $t>0$ we have
$$\alpha+tL(x)\le g(tx)=tg(x).$$So $\alpha/t+L\le g$; let $t\to\infty$ and it follows that $L\le g$

**Edit 2:** This is in reply to a comment, wouldn't fit nicely in the comment box. It's been said that a convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ need not be continuous. Seems to me that yes it *is* continuous:

**Note** I'm taking convex function to be real-valued, as I thought was standard. If we allow convex functions to take values in $(-\infty,\infty]$ then yes, there are certainly discontinuous convex functions on $\Bbb R^n$.

**Heh**, proof that it *is* standard to take "real-valued" as part of the definition: A *standard* result says that any convex function on $\Bbb R$ is continuous..

> > **Lemma** If $f$ is convex on $\Bbb R^n$ then $f$ is bounded above on compact sets.

Proof: Given $K$ compact there exist $x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}$ such that $K$ is contained in the convex hull of the $x_j$: hence $f\le\max(f(x_j))$ on $K$.

Now suppose that $f$ is convex on $\Bbb R^n$. Choose $c$ so that $f(x)\le c$ for $|x|\le 10$.

Suppose $t=|y|< 1$. There exists $z$ with $|z|=1$ such that $y=tz=(1-t)0+tz$.Hence $$f(y)\le tf(z)+(1-t)f(0)\le ct+(1-t)f(0).$$Now $t\to0$ as $y\to0$, so $$f(0)\ge\limsup_{y\to0}f(y).$$For the other direction, say $\alpha=\limsup_{y\to0}f(y)$. Say $y_j\to0$, $f(y_j)\to\alpha$. Let $z_j=-y_j/|y_j|$. Then $0$ is a convex combination of $y_j$ and $z_j$: $$0=t_jz_j+(1-t_j)y_j.$$In particular, $t_j=|(1-t_j)y_j|\to0$. So
$$f(0)\le ct_j+(1-t_j)f(y_j)\to\alpha.$$So $$\limsup_{y\to0}f(y)\le f(0)\le\liminf_{y\to0}f(y),$$hence $\lim_{y\to0}f(y)=f(0).$

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer for $\mathbb{R}$. However, my intention was to find a characterization for general spaces; including, but not limited to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EvanAad ok....

Comment: Thank you. This is much better. Can this result be extended to more general spaces, say abstract vector spaces?

Comment: Well we've covered the finite-dimensional case (at least for real vector spaces; for vector spaces over an arbitrary field there's no notion of convexity in the first place). The same argument works in an infinite-dimensional real vector space, _if_ we know a convex function is the sup of a family of affine functions.

Comment: Besides just being convex, you also want the function to l.s.c in order to have $f = f^{**}$ (Fenchel-Moreau biconjugate theorem), and therefore obtain the announced affine representation. See my answer below.

Comment: @dohmatob It's not clear to me whether your comment is intended as a correction or just a comment on the infinite-dimensional case. It's true that any convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ _is_ lsc, isn't it? It seems to me that's not hard to prove - in fact I suspect that any convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ is actually continuous, altough I haven't quite proved that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My comment is meant to be a correction. (1) Not **every** convex function on $\mathbb R^n$ is l.s.c! What you can prove is that: *On $\mathbb R^n$, a function is l.s.c iff its epigraph is closed*. (2) It's not true that "any convex function on $\mathbb R^n$ is actually continuous". For example, consider the indicator function (in the convex analysis sense, of course) of a singleton $\{a\}$. It is "very discontinuous" at $a$ as it jumps from $0$ to  $\infty$. (3) Etc.

Comment: @dohmatob I'm  missing your point - the indicator function of a singleton is not convex.

Comment: @dohmatob I just saw the words "in the convex analysis sense". I don't know what that means -- what _is_ the indicator function of a singleton "in the convex analysis sense"? (Also, where's the error in the proof I just posted that a convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ is continuous? (See edit to answer above...))

Comment: @dohmatob OK, I looked it up. I was talking about _real-valued_ convex functions - a real-valued convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ must be continuous, yes? (This is the first time I've seen the notion of "convex function" defined to allow $\infty$ as a value...)

Comment: In convex analysis, things only start to become interesting when you bring $\infty$ into the game (e.g think of constrained problems, etc.). Now, If $f$ is convex on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (e.g think of an interval in $\mathbb R^n$), then it cannot be discontnuous at a point $x_0$ where $\limsup_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) < \infty$. In general, all bets are off though (even if you restrict to proper convex functions). I don't have time to produce a non-pathological counter-example, both this shouldn't be too difficult to fabricate.

Comment: @dohmatob I take back the partial retraction in my last comment. So the "indicator function" of $\{a\}$ is given by $f(a)=\infty$, $f(x)=0$ for $x\ne a$, great. How in the world is that convex? You seem to be saying that $\infty\le(f(a+x)+f(a-x))/2=0$.

Comment: @dohmatob But if $f$ is convex (and real-valued) on $\Bbb R^n$ it's very easy to show that $f$ is bounded above on compact sets, (see the Lemma above), so $\limsup f<\infty$ at every point. So yes, every (real-valued) convex function on $\Bbb R^n$ is continuous.

Comment: @dohmatob And come to think of it, if $f$ is just convex (real-valued) on an open set $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ then it's  just as easy to show that $\limsup f<\infty$ at every point of $S$...

Comment: Yep, every function which is **proper** convex on $\mathbb R^n$ is indeed continuous thereupon. Our désaccord appears to ly in what we define as *convex*. The formal definition of convexity allows for the function to take the value $+\infty$. If it never takes on this value (what you appear to have in mind, all along), it's called *proper* convex.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Also, you got the definition of indicator function **wrong**. It's $f(x) = 0 $ if $x = a$ and $f(x) = \infty$ otherwise. Not the other way round. Please be respectful; SE is not youtube. I'm only trying to help here!

Comment: @dohmatob No doubt in some contexts that's the definition. But calling it "the" definition is a major exaggeration - the definition is often, if not typically, explicitly restricted to real-valued functions. My copy of Rudin is missing - just looked it up in Folland _Real Analysis_.

Comment: @dohmatob Ah. Can't find my copy of Rudin, but come to think of it I an nonetheless be certain that his convex functions are real-valued, because he proves that a convex function on $(a,b)$ is continuous. So that's two very standard texts that have the definition wrong? No doubt allowing $+\infty$ makes the theory nicer in some ways, just as we want to allow $-\infty$ as a value for subharmonic functions. But for future reference you might bear in mind that for many if not most people the standard definition is that a convex function is real-valued.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, for most people outside convex analysis, that's probably how convex functions are (inadequately) defined / thought of. Folland, Robin, etc. are not references on the subject either. Once again, things only start becoming even vaguely interesting when you allow for infinities. All the interesting theories in the subject are built w.r.t to convex functions with co-domain $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Let's leave it at that, as the conversation seems to be getting unnecessarily long without contributing anything valuable, neither to the original question nor general culture. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By the [Fenchel-Moreau (aka Biconjugate) Theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Fenchel-Moreau), all lower-semicontinuous convex funnctions on a *Hausdorff locally convex space* can be represented as a supremum of *affine* functions

Indeed, for such functions, one has $f^{**} = f$, i.e

$$
f(x) \equiv \sup_{y}x^Ty - f^*(y),
$$
a supremum of **affine** functions.

Comment: Thanks, however my question was about the supremum of *linear* functions; not affine ones.

Comment: This is no big deal. I've provided you with something more general. Your question now translates to "when is $f^*(y)$ piecewise linear" ?

Comment: So what is the answer to my question, then? Or (to take your word for it, because I don't quite understand your answer) when is $f^*(y)$ piecewise linear? Or maybe you meant to say that the answer to my question is: $f$ can be represented as the supremum of linear functions whenever $f^*$ is piecewise linear?